# RDCOMClient package: How to read data from a query

Tags: mysql, r, com, ado, rdcomclient

I am currently on the issue to connect to a Cube with R using .COM objects, to then gathering data from the Cube via mdx-queries. As in my previous question described (see link below), I can now connect to the cube with the help of the RDCOMClient package and R version 3.3.1, and can also send queries to the cube.
Moreover, when tracing my connection with the SQL Server Profiler, I can see it connected correctly + I also see that my query is executed without errors.

However, I have no idea how I can obtain my data inside R. I save the query result in the variable results, but I am unable to do anything with it. Can you help me display my query results in R please?

.

**Connection + Query Code:**

```
conn = COMCreate("ADODB.Connection")

connStr = 'my connection string'
conn[["ConnectionString"]] = connStr 

conn$Open()
conn[["State"]]  

query = 'some query. 100% correct, tested with other tools'
results = conn$Execute(query)
```

.

**Information for the results variable:  (Code, followed by the Output)**

```
names = slotNames(results)
names
```

> [1] "ref"

.

```
slot(results,names[1])
```

> pointer: 0x0000000015d63c60

.

```
str(results)
```

> Formal class 'COMIDispatch' [package "RDCOMClient"] with 1 slot
>
> ..@ ref:

.

```
class(results)
```

> [1] "COMIDispatch"
>     attr(,"package")
>     [1] "RDCOMClient"

.

```
attributes(results)
```

> $ref
>
> $class
>
> [1] "COMIDispatch"
>
> attr(,"package")
>
> [1] "RDCOMClient"

.

**Thanks for helping :-)**

.

Previous question: [R & COM-Objects: How to connect to a OLAP cube on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042980/r-com-objects-how-to-connect-to-a-olap-cube-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using ADO's [GetRows()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675120(v=vs.85).aspx) method which returns records of a recordset in a nested VBA array which would translate into a nested R list. Currently, you only retrieve the recordset object.

```
results = conn$Execute(query)$GetRows()
```